# issue with apache upgrade 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, ldap

Upgraded my httpd from 2.2 to 2.4 and getting this error when I try to start httpd:

```
~]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 164 of 
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ldap.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so: undefined symbol: ap_escape_html [FAILED]
```

Can anyone help how to fix this issue. I am using ldap on my apache config so I cannot comment out the module

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Comment: Hi Erki,
to upgrade Apache:
I took a backup of /etc/httpd
Ran: yum update httpd
which updated it from httpd-2.15 to httpd-2.40
and getting the error above when I try to start the httpd service

Here are the spec of my server:
~]# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: ~]# uname  -r
2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64

]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix)
Server built:   Jun 29 2016 19:48:11


# httpd -S
httpd: Syntax error on line 164 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ldap.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so: undefined symbol: ap_escape_html